# decltype on type expressions

Tags: c++, templates, decltype

Is there any way to avoid the dummy functions in the following example?

```
template<class T1, class T2>
struct A {

    static T1 T1_ ();
    static T2 T2_ ();

    typedef decltype (T1_ () + T2_ ()) sum_type;
};
```

I would like to write

```
typedef decltype (T1+T2) sum_type;
```

but that's not possible since `T1` and `T2` are types, not variables. Is my above solution really the easiest one possible?

Comment: `typedef decltype(*(T1*)0 + *(T2*)0) sum_type;` avoids the functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Holy Standard provides **`std::declval`** for exactly this purpose:

```
typedef decltype (declval<T1>()+declval<T2>()) sum_type;
```

Include the `<utility>` header.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I need. Never heard about it. Visual C++ 2010 does not seem to have it, but now declared it myself by `template<class T> T declval ();`.

Comment: @JohnB: The correct one is `template<class T> typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval();`.

Comment: Hm, shouldn't be the result of a function an rvalue anyway? I fully trust in what you say, but I do not understand why simple `T` does not suffice.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
typedef decltype(*(T1*)0 + *(T2*)0) sum_type;
```